# how to check an array value through input value?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, input

I want to code a programme which can read the values from the user inputs of the strings and can verify whether that string matches any array or not. If it matches, then the program would return that string in the HTML tag

.

I have declared an array named "cars" and created a Loop through it which would check each individual value of the array. every time I am getting the string "Not Available".

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Check Whether it is present or not</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Design.css" />
    </head>
    <body>        
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txt">
            <input type="button" value="Check" id="btn">
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="para">para</p>
        </div>
        <script src="Soul.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>



function check() {

    let intText = document.getElementById("txt").value;
    let cars = ["Lamborghini", "BMW", "Ferrari"];

    for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        if (intText == cars[i]) {
            return document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = cars[i] + " is present";
        }
        else {
            return document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "Not Available";
        } 
    }
    return cars;
}

btn.addEventListener('click', check, false);
```

if the user inputs BMW, it must return "BMW is present"
similarly, Lamborghini must return "Lamborghini is present"
but
Bugatti must return "Not Present"

Comment: Instead of using a `==` condition, use `indexOf` incase of array values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use loop unless needed

```
    function check() {

        let intText = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        let cars = ["Lamborghini", "BMW", "Ferrari"];
        if(cars.includes(intText)){
        document.getElementById("para").innerHTML =intText + " is present";
        } else {
        document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "Not Available";
        }   
    }

    btn.addEventListener('click', check, false);
```

```
        <head>
            <title>Check Whether it is present or not</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="Design.css" />
        </head>
        <body>        
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="txt">
                <input type="button" value="Check" id="btn">
            </div>
            <div>
                <p id="para">para</p>
            </div>
            <script src="Soul.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `include` to find the match in the array. for loop is not needed.

```
cars.includes(intText)
let intText = document.getElementById("txt").value;
let cars = ["Lamborghini", "BMW", "Ferrari"];
```

```js
function check() {

    let intText = document.getElementById("txt").value;
    let cars = ["Lamborghini", "BMW", "Ferrari"];

    if(cars.includes(intText)){
      return document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = intText + " is present";
      }
      else {
         return document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "Not Available"
       }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', check, false);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Check Whether it is present or not</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Design.css" />
    </head>
    <body>        
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txt">
            <input type="button" value="Check" id="btn">
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="para">para</p>
        </div>
        <script src="Soul.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by simple condition:

```js
var input = "BMW";
var input2 = "Peugeot"


function checkCar(car){
   var cars = ["BMW", "Lambo", "Bugatti"];
   if(!!~cars.indexOf(car)){
      return car+" is present";
   }
   return car+" not present";
}

console.log(checkCar(input));
console.log(checkCar(input2));
```

The key is the formula of `!!~cars.indexOf(car)` which simply returns true if the value is in array (and it works also for strings)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Check Whether it is present or not</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Design.css" />
    </head>
    <body>        
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txt">
            <input type="button" value="Check" id="btn">
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="para">para</p>
        </div>
        <script src="Soul.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

<script>

function check() {

    let intText = document.getElementById("txt").value;
    let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    let cars = ["Lamborghini", "BMW", "Ferrari"];

    let text = "Not Available";
    for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        let car = cars[i];
        if (intText == car) {
            text = car;
            break;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = text + " is present";
}

btn.addEventListener('click', check, false);

</script>
```

You should break the loop when matched.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function check() {
    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "";
    let intText = document.getElementById("txt").value;
    let cars = ["Lamborghini", "BMW", "Ferrari"];
    var flag=cars.indexOf(intText);
    if (flag>-1)return document.getElementById("para").innerHTML =intText + " is present";
    else return document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "Not Available";
 }
btn.addEventListener('click', check, false);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Check Whether it is present or not</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Design.css" />
    </head>
    <body>        
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txt">
            <input type="button" value="Check" id="btn">
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="para"/>
        </div>
        <script src="Soul.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function check() {

  let intText = document.getElementById("txt").value;
  let cars = ["Lamborghini", "BMW", "Ferrari"];

  if (cars.indexOf(intText) !== -1) {
    return document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = intText + " is present";
  } else {
    return document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "Not Available";
  }

  return cars;
}

btn.addEventListener('click', check, false);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Check Whether it is present or not</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Design.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="txt">
    <input type="button" value="Check" id="btn">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p id="para"></p>
  </div>
  <script src="Soul.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```